# Copying geometry (not attributes) from feature in layer 1, to a feature in layer 2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Having trouble copying the shape of a polygon in a parcels layer feature to the shape of a polygon I'd like to change in a water districts layer.  I don't want to exchange the attributes from the parcel layer to water district layer, *only* shape.

Attached is a screenshot of the two features (each in a different layer) in question.  The goal is to copy the shape of the parcel outlined in green roughly beneath the blue water district feature laying on top of it.  The boundaries should be matching, but as you can see the blue water district layer is going over the road, doesn't include some houses in its southeast portion it should, includes some houses in its lower power it shouldn't, etc.  [image: Green parcel boundary and blue water district boundary which should match]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[Spatial Adjustment tools](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment-attribute-transfer.htm)** to transfer either/or attributes and geometry. If you are just wanting to transfer the geometry just tick the box and do not include any attribute fields.

Comment: Please note, pressing Refresh (F5) was necessary for me to see changes.